How to connect to an Oracle7 database
I have an ancient Oracle7 database (version 7.3.4.5.0) that I need to extract some data from.
I mainly work with Python, so naturally I started looking at oracledb. However, it looks like the oldest version of oracledb only supports Oracle 9 and up (got erro DPY-4011 when attempting a connection).
So I started looking at cx_Oracle instead. It looks like I should probably use cx_Oracle 3.0 or older.
However I can't find any binary distributables for it. Are they available anywhere? If not, can I install it directly from PyPi somehow?
If all fails, is there any other way to write a script for Oracle7 (VBScript?, JScript?, VBA?) that's documented?

Extended Support for Oracle 7 ended in 2003 (over 20 years ago). If you are paying a support contract to Oracle then contact Oracle Support; if not, then you are using an out-dated, unsupported product that should have been upgraded 25 years ago and, no, there is probably not a simple solution. You may be better to try to backup the database using exp and then import imp it into a newer (supported) database rather than trying to connect to something ancient. However, this is all off-topic for StackOverflow.

If you forget about anything BUT Oracle itself, can you connect to that database? The oldfashioned way is to use its own SQL*Plus. If you actually can do that, then you'd be able to write SELECT statement(s), extract data you need (spool the result into a CSV file) and then simply import contents of these CSV files into ... something (whatever the target is).

@Littlefoot: Yes, I've managed to connect using SQLPlus and spool to file. However this project requires me to spool thousands and thousands of lines, maybe ~30 columns, to to multiple CSV files. I didn't find the SQLPlus SPOOL functionality powerful enough.

The first way. If you have access to the server, you can upload data in csv format on the server. To do this, you will need to write a script for the sqlplus utility, this utility is on all Oracle servers. You will not need to install anything. The second way is more complicated. Make a dump of the necessary schemes on Oracle 7, using the exp utility. Import the data into a more modern Oracle DB, for example 11.2.0.4 minimum, using the imp utility for this.

I wonder if there are legacy odbc drivers you can use. Perhaps this might help https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/legacy-application-with-very-specific-client-versions-7229

Try installing cx_Oracle directly from PyPI using normal package version selection syntax: python -m pip install cx_Oracle==5.1.3 The oldest code available is 5.1.3.  I personally would try 5.3 first, since that just predates the use of the ODPI-C layer which is when the minimum Oracle Client library jumped to 11.2. You will need to make sure old Oracle client libraries are available (e.g. the ones in your Oracle Home directory) since they are really the things that affect connectivity. You'll likely need an older environment - neither 5.1.3 or 5.3 build for me with recent Python versions.

If you go the cx_Oracle route, don't forget to tune the arraysize setting, see https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/write_csv.py

Try use SQLPlus, which can be used to extract data from Oracle7 directly. You could write scripts in SQLPlus to extract data, then use Python to process the exported data (e.g., CSV files).
An Example using python:
import subprocess
command = "sqlplus -S username/password@your_database @your_script.sql"
subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
